# Real-world Applications of Integer Factorization

Tags: prime-factorization, integers

All of us know the extensive application of integer factorization in Cryptography.
But, I would like to know its applications in other fields.

If anyone knows some applications of integer factorization with applications in data science or data mining. Please state them as well.

Comment: I meant the areas where factorization plays an important role in solving the problems.

Comment: My professor asked to find out these areas to work on.

Comment: In group theory, the prime factorization plays an important role. For example, the number of groups of order $n$ upto isomorphy heavily depends on the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: The prime factorization can also be useful to find divisibility-rules. For example, when is a number divisible by $7$ ?

Comment: I use integer factorization whenever I simplify fractions.

Comment: The primality (non-amenability to factorisation) of numbers can be significant in biology. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodical_cicadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field of *Combinatorics*.

---

For example:

> Find the number of positive integer divisors of $48$.

---

Using the prime factorization of $48=2^4\cdot3^1$, we can easily answer this question:

- In each divisor, the factor $2$ can appear between $0$ and $4$ times, i.e., $5$ different combinations
- In each divisor, the factor $3$ can appear between $0$ and $1$ times, i.e., $2$ different combinations

Hence there are $5\cdot2=10$ divisors:

- $2^0\cdot3^0$
- $2^0\cdot3^1$
- $2^1\cdot3^0$
- $2^1\cdot3^1$
- $2^2\cdot3^0$
- $2^2\cdot3^1$
- $2^3\cdot3^0$
- $2^3\cdot3^1$
- $2^4\cdot3^0$
- $2^4\cdot3^1$